# Access non static method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class Canvas {
    public void erase(){}
}
```

I want to use that erase method in another class but since it doesn´t appear to be static, I can´t just do this

```
public class Country {
    Canvas.erase();
}
```

So how do I access that method then?

Comment: Invoke the method on an instance of `Canvas`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567360/calling-non-static-methods-from-other-classes

Comment: Have you tried passing `Canvas canvas` as an argument to your method?

Answer (score 2):

you'd need to create first an object (instance) of the class, and then call its methods, eg :

```
Canvas canvasInstance = new Canvas();
canvasInstance.erase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only options is:

1. Make the method static

   public **static** void erase(){}
2. Call the method from an instance of Canvas

   new Canvas().erase();

Answer (score 0):

Non static method can be called with object refence only. Create an instance of Canvas class and then call erase method like,

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.erase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do it have a static reference of `Canvas` so this is how to do it:

```
public class Canvas
{
    public static Canvas cObj;

    public void erase() { }
} 


public class Country {

    public void CallMethod()
    {
        Canvas.cObj.erase();
    }
}
```

That way you would be able to call erase on Class Canvas easily from class County